# facebook.sdk error 5 Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm a newbie in objective-c and I really need your help. I've been trying to solve this for hours now. And I still can't find a solution. Here is my codes:

```
-(void)post
{

        [self connectWithFacebook];
        NSLog(@"session: %hhd", FBSession.activeSession.isOpen);

        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Here's to the Crazy Ones" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSURL *pathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        NSDictionary *videoObject = @{
                                      @"title": @"FB SDK 3.1",
                                      @"description": @"hello there !",
                                      [pathURL absoluteString]: videoData
                                      };
        FBRequest *uploadRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                        parameters:videoObject
                                                        HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSLog(@"here i am");
        [uploadRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"after upload request");
            if (!error)
                NSLog(@"Done: %@", result);
            else
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }];

}
```

AND

```
- (void) connectWithFacebook {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}
```

And here's from the AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    NSArray *permissions = @[@"publish_stream"];

    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                             if (error) {
                                                 NSLog (@"Handle error %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                             } else {
                                                 NSLog(@"No error");
                                             }
                                         }];
}
```

Here's from the console:

2014-05-08 15:02:49.385 camera[3748:60b] Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you. I really have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Have you read through the Facebook error handling guide - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/ ?  The FBErrorUtility class could give you some more information

Comment: Yes, I did. The first one I did was sort of like a loop, when the session is not open yet, it tries and tries. The app hangs

Comment: What does [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error]; show?

Comment: Also this - http://www.abdus.me/ios-programming-tips/com-facebook-sdk-error-5-irritating-isnt-it/  but it may be that your video upload takes too long times out?

Comment: [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error]; shows null right now. Still, the error is 5.

Comment: The upload stops I think, because it just shows me an error 5 while I wait.

Answer (score 0):

one possible error for com.facebook.sdk error 5 is

> "This status update is identical to the last one you posted. Try
>   posting something different, or delete your previous update."